# cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render out the dropdown menu items from DropDown.js whenever i click on ***Services*** button from Navbar.js. However, when i click on Services button i got this error "***You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than one in your app.***". How can i fix this? Please help me! Thank you so much!

DropDown.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { serviceDropdown } from "./NavItems";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./DropDown.css";

function DropDown() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="subnav-items">
        {serviceDropdown.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Router>
              <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            </Router>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DropDown;
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { navItems } from "./NavItems";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

function Navbar() {
  const [dropDown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav-items">
        {navItems.map((item) => {
          if (item.title === "Services") {
            return (
              <Router>
                <li
                  key={item.id}
                  className={item.cName}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setDropdown(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setDropdown(false)}
                >
                  <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
                  {dropDown && <DropDown />}
                </li>
              </Router>
            );
            
          }
          return (
            <Router>
              <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            </Router>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like the invariant error says, you should only have one router providing a routing context to the entire app, or at a minimum, not have any nested routers. Remove all the extraneous `Router` components wrapping each individual list item/`Link`, and ensure you've only one wrapping the app.

DropDown.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { serviceDropdown } from "./NavItems";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./DropDown.css";

function DropDown() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="subnav-items">
        {serviceDropdown.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
              <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DropDown;
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { navItems } from "./NavItems";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

function Navbar() {
  const [dropDown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav-items">
        {navItems.map((item) => {
          if (item.title === "Services") {
            return (
              <li
                key={item.id}
                className={item.cName}
                onMouseEnter={() => setDropdown(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setDropdown(false)}
              >
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
                {dropDown && <DropDown />}
              </li>
            );
          }
          return (
            <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
              <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

App example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

return (
  <Router>
    <DropDown />
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      .... routes here ....
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);
```